# Cartesian product of countable set A.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each $j=1,2,3,..$ let $A_j$ be a finite set containing at-least two distinct elements. Then,

1. $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$ is a countable set.
2. $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{n} A_j$ is uncountable.
3. $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$ is uncountable.
4. $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$ is uncountable.

Now we know that countable union of countable sets is countable. Hence $1$ is true and $4$ is false. Also $2$ is false. But I am not sure about $3$. Help me out.

Comment: But cartesian product of two countable sets is countable, so finite cartesian product is countable. Right? @S.Panja-1729

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed 3. is uncountable.

The idea is that $$\vert \prod_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j \vert \ge \vert \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \{0,1\} \vert$$ and that the later set has the power of the continuum as it is in bijection with the segment $[0,1)$ when you think to the binary expansion of a real number.

Comment: So the later one is also uncountable. @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: No. If there is no error in your post. Which might be as the sets in 1 and 4 are the same? Anyhow, a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: No I mean $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\{0,1\}$ is also uncountable right?

Comment: Yes. That's right. It is uncountable.